# entity framework Database First with Visual Studio 2008

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio-2008

I need to access an existing database.
How can I Use Database First to create a boxes and lines model that maps to an existing database with **Visual Studio 2008**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have .NET 3.5 SP1 and VS 2008 SP1 - that was the first version where EF was available. After that you will have ADO.NET Entity Data Model item available for adding to your projects. Once you add the item, a wizard will run and you will be able to define the source database for your database first approach.

Comment: Could you please describe more and show pictures and videos?
Thanks

Comment: I have .NET 3.5 SP1 and VS 2008 SP1 But it has not ADO.NET Entity Data Model in data section!
What should I do?